# How do I use JQuery $.get() method

Tags: php, jquery

How to send an HTTP GET request to a page and get a result back:
This is a piece of code using jquery pagination..
I think there is a mistake in my code is to call $.get() on a jquery method.

```
if(isset($_GET['pages'])) {

    $pages = $_GET['pages'];
    $i = ($pages - 1) * $num_pages  + 1;
    .....

    <?php echo '<a href="?pages='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>' ?>
```

this Jquery code:

```
//JQuery

(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        var main = "data_students.php";

        $("#data-students").load(main);

        // when the button page is pressed 
        $('.pages').live("click", function(event){
            kd_page = this.id;

            $.get(main, {pages: kd_page} ,function(data) {
                $("#data-students").html(data).show();
            });
        });
    });
}) (jQuery);
```

Comment: are you getting any error? check it in developer tools console

Comment: Error in console? FYI, as for jq 1.9, `live is dead`...

Comment: ok, i will be change `$(document).on("click", '.pages', function(event){`, but doesn't work.. :(

Comment: what 'doesnt work'? are you getting an error? what is the output? we all need information to help you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get("page.php?vars=values&othervar=othervalue",function(data) {
            $("#data-students").html(data).show();
        });
```

Comment: you can add all parameters you need

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
//send as much paramerters as you wish in $.get(url,data,callback);

$.get("page.php",{vars:values,othervar:othervalue},function(data) {
        $("#data-students").html(data).show();
    });
```

Comment: `$.get(main, {pages: kd_page}, function(data) {`

Comment: sory, I am just learning. This is an example of someone else's code. who should be using POST .. 
`$ Pages = $ _POST['pages'];` 
and called the `<li class="pages" id="<?php echo $i ?>"><a href="#"><?php echo $i ?></a></li>`
contents of jquery code: `$.posts(main, {pages: kd_page}, function(data) {`
 i just want to change it to use GET. so it will appear in the url.